# How disable auto formatting on CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I handling when data on a field that is using CKEditor is changing, 
Save button is enabled.
But, after i set data (by Javascript) into the field, Change event always is occured, SO that, Save button alway is enable though the field is not changed.

Please help me to disable auto format function on CKEditor.

Comment: CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CKEditor fires `change` event every time it save undo spanshot so if you want to set data without such snapshot you need to use `noSpanshot` option:

```
editor.setData('foo', {noSnapshot: true});
```